# I can't upload files bigger then 20 M to my S3 bucket

Tags: s3fs

I recently created a S3 bucket at Scaleway.
I mount it using s3fs without apparent problem.
I have problems uploading some "mid size" files. 
If the size under 20 M it's ok but for with larger files (50 M and more), the copy fails with message "unable to write file, permission denied".
I contacter scaleway support but they said it's related to my s3fs client.
I mounted the bucket in debug mode, using :

```
$ sudo s3fs tellurix /mnt/scaleway/ -o passwd_file=${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs,url=https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud,allow_other -o use_path_request_style,noatime -o dbglevel=info -f -o curldbg
```

I copy/paste the 100 last lines of the log, because I don't see where the error is .
Thanks a lot for help

```
* SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
* Closing connection 6
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2546): ### CURLE_SEND_ERROR
* SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
* Closing connection 5
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2546): ### CURLE_SEND_ERROR
[INF] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2621): ### retrying...
[INF]       curl.cpp:RemakeHandle(2248): Retry request. [type=9][url=https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=5&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1][path=/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf]
* Hostname s3.fr-par.scw.cloud was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 2001:bc8:1002::30:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to s3.fr-par.scw.cloud (2001:bc8:1002::30) port 443 (#6)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL re-using session ID
* SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
* Closing connection 5
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2546): ### CURLE_SEND_ERROR
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=s3.fr-par.scw.cloud
*  start date: Feb 10 23:20:22 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May 10 23:20:22 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "s3.fr-par.scw.cloud" matched cert's "s3.fr-par.scw.cloud"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> PUT /tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=5&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1 HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.fr-par.scw.cloud
User-Agent: s3fs/1.86 (commit hash 005a684; OpenSSL)
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 10485760
Expect: 100-continue

* SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
* Closing connection 6
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2546): ### CURLE_SEND_ERROR
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< x-amz-id-2: tx97bf2f1b3ccd47c4a5f91-005eaa999a
< x-amz-request-id: tx97bf2f1b3ccd47c4a5f91-005eaa999a
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 09:25:46 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
* HTTP error before end of send, keep sending
< 
[INF] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2621): ### retrying...
[INF]       curl.cpp:RemakeHandle(2248): Retry request. [type=9][url=https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=2&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1][path=/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf]
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2639): ### giving up
[WAN] curl.cpp:MultiPerform(4340): thread failed - rc(-5)
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2797): computing signature [PUT] [/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf] [partNumber=6&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1] [34ec149b334729973e407bada5e11b96774acfd1375b8009f789474ecb9bb2bb]
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud
* Hostname s3.fr-par.scw.cloud was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 2001:bc8:1002::30:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to s3.fr-par.scw.cloud (2001:bc8:1002::30) port 443 (#7)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL re-using session ID
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=s3.fr-par.scw.cloud
*  start date: Feb 10 23:20:22 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May 10 23:20:22 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "s3.fr-par.scw.cloud" matched cert's "s3.fr-par.scw.cloud"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> PUT /tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=6&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1 HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.fr-par.scw.cloud
User-Agent: s3fs/1.86 (commit hash 005a684; OpenSSL)
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxx/20200430/fr-par/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=91bbf50cc33a1f1d1cd3f3660fcc116e857223b4f8297b6c796e7dc32f244bac
x-amz-content-sha256: 34ec149b334729973e407bada5e11b96774acfd1375b8009f789474ecb9bb2bb
x-amz-date: 20200430T092546Z
Content-Length: 1132789
Expect: 100-continue

[INF] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2621): ### retrying...
[INF]       curl.cpp:RemakeHandle(2248): Retry request. [type=9][url=https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=1&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1][path=/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf]
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2639): ### giving up
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
* Closing connection 6
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2546): ### CURLE_SEND_ERROR
[INF] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2621): ### retrying...
[INF]       curl.cpp:RemakeHandle(2248): Retry request. [type=9][url=https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=3&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1][path=/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf]
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2639): ### giving up
[INF] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2621): ### retrying...
[INF]       curl.cpp:RemakeHandle(2248): Retry request. [type=9][url=https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=4&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1][path=/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf]
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2639): ### giving up
[INF] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2621): ### retrying...
[INF]       curl.cpp:RemakeHandle(2248): Retry request. [type=9][url=https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=5&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1][path=/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf]
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2639): ### giving up
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 0
< x-amz-id-2: tx64fa48b5fffb4985bee17-005eaa999a
< Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 09:25:46 GMT
< ETag: "30c5132a619a14608ff0a3d9bac63fe2"
< x-amz-request-id: tx64fa48b5fffb4985bee17-005eaa999a
< x-amz-version-id: 1588238746862950
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 09:25:59 GMT
< 
* Connection #7 to host s3.fr-par.scw.cloud left intact
[INF]       curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2455): HTTP response code 200
[WAN] curl.cpp:MultiPerform(4374): thread failed - rc(-5)
[WAN] curl.cpp:MultiPerform(4374): thread failed - rc(-5)
[WAN] curl.cpp:MultiPerform(4374): thread failed - rc(-5)
[WAN] curl.cpp:MultiPerform(4374): thread failed - rc(-5)
[WAN] curl.cpp:MultiRead(4400): error from callback function(https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=1&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1).
[WAN] curl.cpp:MultiRead(4400): error from callback function(https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=2&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1).
[WAN] curl.cpp:MultiRead(4400): error from callback function(https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=3&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1).
[WAN] curl.cpp:MultiRead(4400): error from callback function(https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=4&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1).
[WAN] curl.cpp:MultiRead(4400): error from callback function(https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/tellurix/ant/MyHome%20automation%20guide%2072488.pdf?partNumber=5&uploadId=YmNkMmE3MWMtMDFhYi00NDhmLTlkYWItMjEyMDA1YTM1Njk1).
[INF]       curl.cpp:CompleteMultipartPostRequest(3642): [tpath=/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf][parts=6]
[ERR] curl.cpp:CompleteMultipartPostRequest(3653): 1 file part is not finished uploading.
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_release(2358): [path=/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf][fd=11]
[INF]       cache.cpp:DelStat(582): delete stat cache entry[path=/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf]
[INF]       fdcache.cpp:GetFdEntity(2650): [path=/ant/MyHome automation guide 72488.pdf][fd=11]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully mounted and wrote a 500 MB file to scaleway using your command-line arguments. Given the CURLE_SEND_ERROR I wonder if you have some kind of network problem? Maybe try a lower value for -o parallel_count, e.g., 1?  See https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/1283#issuecomment-623026911 for the resolution.

Comment: Hi, this is the same issue. Setting  parallel_count to 2 fixed the problem. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

From where do you mount your bucket? Is it your PC in your home or a cloud VM? How  much time does it take before you receive this error?

I'm asking because "SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32" looks like something is closing your connection. "HTTP error before end of send, keep sending" also points for that kind of problem. A timeout maybe occurs? Do you have a NAT gateway between you and your bucket? That can also cause the problem, if it does not care about keepalives as the upload can take relatively long.

As the s3fs wiki says, 20MB is the threshold for multipart uploads instead of single request. Maybe Scaleway has a slightly different API for multipart uploads than Amazon? From the s3fs wiki: "Some providers do not support the full S3 API, e.g., lacking multi-part upload." Please make note that s3fs is mainly intended to work with Amazon S3 and, as I see, Scaleway is not on the list of supported providers in the s3fs wiki: https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Non-Amazon-S3.

The last thing, what's your version of libcurl? The s3fs documentation says it should be 7.16 or 7.17. And are you using the latest version of s3fs?

Comment: Thanks for answering an for the information. You were right. Changing  parallel_count parameter as per Andrew suggestion fixed the problem. Thank you.